# Minimal surface contained in a hemisphere

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, spherical-geometry, minimal-surfaces

I am looking for examples of closed, orientable minimal surfaces of the sphere $\mathbb{S}^3$ that are contained in a hemisphere. Do you know any?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen this survey article: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.6938.pdf ?

Comment: I know this survey. I recently received the answer that such a minimal surface must be an equator.

Comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/24898531?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents